# Xrm.sdk and Sharepoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint, crm, xrm

I need to take data from a Dynamic CRM 2013 tables using web services.

In a Console Application I used microsoft.xrm.sdk.dll and it was so easy to make query using QueryExpression.

But now I need to do the same thing and represent data on an Application Page for SharePoint 2013 Project.
And I used the same way, but there is exception:

Could not load file or assembly "Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=****************" or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your VS project --> expand References --> click on the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk assembly --> lock at it's properties and make sure it's set to Copy Local = true.

If that still doesn't work, try adding the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk assembly to the SharePoint server GAC. On the server, run `gacutil -i [path to assembly]`